# JS charting library with good performance

Tags: gratis, library, javascript, data-visualization, charts

I have some data in .csv format (~10000 records or more) and I need visualize them in charts (Area and line charts in the main).  Also charts must be interactive and to have controllers and filters. 
Now I am using google charts, but it has problem with performance for such volume of data.

So requirements are :

1. JS library for drawing charts.
2. Good performance with data about 10000 records.
3. Manipulate charts by filters according to data as well as google chart. I mean [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) feature, specifically *CategoryFilter* and *ChartRangeFilter*
4. Free
5. Cross browser

Comment: What kind of charts do you need? Not that I have something in mind, but knowing what's needed and what not might help others to give good recommendations. Also possibly relevant: Amount and format of data to be processed (as you speak of "big data").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Essential Chart for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/chart/line) is an option.

1. JS library for drawing charts: Yes
2. Good performance with data about 10000 records: Yes. Refer to [sample](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/i11wh2zj).
3. Manipulate charts by filters according to data as well as google chart.: Yes. see sample linked to above.
4. Free: Community license available (see details below)
5. Cross browser: Yes.

[image: Essential Chart JavaScript performance]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

> dc.js is a **javascript** charting library with native **crossfilter** support and allowing **highly efficient exploration on large multi-dimensional dataset** (inspired by crossfilter's demo). It leverages d3 engine to render charts in css friendly svg format. Charts rendered using dc.js are naturally data driven and reactive therefore providing instant feedback on user's interaction. The main objective of this project is to provide an easy yet powerful javascript library which can be utilized to perform data visualization and analysis in browser as well as on mobile device.

(Emphasis added)

> dc.js is an open source javascript library and licensed under Apache License v2.

I've used it with a 70,000 record csv file. Very responsive after the data loads.